# How UITableView show two different arrays one at a time?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, uitableview, subclass

The below Code works but not as i wish.i want that when i click UIbutton its automaically update the new value in UITableview instead of old value.Below Code works only when i press the UIbuttons and after that when i scroll the UITableview then it update the UItableview with new values.
In my application i using UITableview as Subclass of my mainclass.as image show below

[image]

I add Tableview in my Mainclass which is "testingViewController" like this way 
In testingViewController.h

```
#import "Inputtableview.h"
@interface testingViewController :UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> {
     Inputtableview *inputview;
     IBOutlet UITableView *inputtbl; 
}
@end
```

In testingViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
btn1bool=FALSE;
if (inputview == nil) {
    inputview = [[Inputtableview alloc] init];
}

[inputtbl setDataSource:inputview];
[inputtbl setDelegate:inputview];
inputview.view = inputview.tableView;
}
```

Now in Button action method

```
-(IBAction)input:(id)sender
  {
  btn1bool=TRUE;
}
```

my Subclass code "inputtableview.m" is show below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
listOfItems=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Iceland",@"Greenland",@"Switzerland",
             @"Norway",@"New Zealand",@"Greece",@"Italy",@"Ireland",nil];

  array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H", nil] ;
 }

  #pragma mark -
  #pragma mark Table View datasource methods
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
    if (btn1bool) {
        return [array1 count];
    }
else {
    return [listOfItems count];
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
   }


 -(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSLog(@"Row: %i", indexPath.row);
if (btn1bool) {
    NSString *cellValue = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.text = cellValue;
}
else {
    NSString *cellValue = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.text = cellValue;
      }
   return cell;
 }
```

Any help will be appriated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the following code:

```
[inputtbl reloadData];
```

There are a few things you need to change in your project, but I assume this project is just for testing stuff.

---

You want the date to reload after you pressed the button, so you call the method in the IBAction.

```
-(IBAction)input:(id)sender
{
    btn1bool=TRUE;
    [inputview.tableView reloadData];
}
```

To switch between the 2 data sources when the button is pressed you can change to this line of code: `btn1bool=!btn1bool;`

```
(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (btn1bool) {
        return [array1 count];
    } else {
        return [listOfItems count];
    }
}
```

`-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is correct

Comment: inputtableview is a subclass of testingViewController?

Comment: You need a strong reference to the table view so you can make it reload. Probably `inputview.tableView` is not referencing to the table view, or else it would reload, and get you expected result.

Comment: At the IBAction, make sure `inputview` isnt nil and `inputview.tableView` isnt nil. You can do this by `NSLog(@"inputView:%@ tableView"%@", inputview, inputview.tableView);`.  Or simply set a break point and check the self variables.

Comment: please Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290340/xcode-tableview-showing-to-different-arrays-one-at-a-time-problem it just like my problem only difference is that i using UITableview as Subclass and he is using UiTableview as subview.

Comment: Are you using storyboard? To what class are you creating the IBOutlet to your tableview. I dont understand why you are subclassing to create the UITableView. Do you need some very specific behavior?