# How to Assign Text to UILabel in MainClass using Subclass Function?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uilabel, subclass

I have a UILabel in Mainclass, now I want to Assign it text by Subclass function. My question detail code is available here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312739/how-uitableview-show-two-different-arrays-one-at-a-time) Now I want that when I click on any Cell of my UITableview (which is my Subclass) its text assign to UILabel in Mainview. my Code is below which I tried so for

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
NSLog(@"MY row Text:%@",cellText);

// Now here I don't know how we can pass this text to UILabel which is in my mainclass

}
```

My Below image also helpful for understanding my problem

[image]

Comment: What is the relationship between "Mainview" and the code you show in this question?

Comment: @PhillipMills the code i show here is my subclass code which is Subclass of Mainview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass label on to the subview class when you create it.

In the main view class declare:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *mainLabel;
// or if no ARC
// @property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *mainLabel;
```

Then on the .h for the subview, declare:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UILabel *myAccessToMainLabel;
// or if no ARC
// @property (nonatomic, assign) UILabel *myAccessToMainLabel;
```

When the subview is created, assign the main view's Label to the subview's myAccessToMainLabel. Then assign the label in the subview code. You can always pass around properties in Objective-c.

Edit:
When you create the subview, assign mainLabel to subview's reference iVar from the code that create it.For example, if the main create the subview then:

```
MySubViewClass *mySubView = [[MySubViewClass alloc] initWithNib:@"MySubViewClass" ...];
// or any variety of init
mySubview.myAccessToMainLabel = mainLabel;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass reference of the label to the subclass.  Then subclass can simple set the text of the label.

Add property UILabel *mainLabel in the table view controller.
Then set this property to the label reference from the main class.

Comment: Can u please explain your answer that how we can pass the reference of mainclass label to subclass